# Is there a way to update/add info into database with php submit button?

Tags: php, sql

i have a paypal intergated shopping cart. Since the payment button go to the paypal site, i cant do a sql database add/update . Is there a way to insert information when i click on the button best is without usign Ajax(most suggested using it) since i have totally no knowledge about it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, just use the `header();` function of PHP. If you have a button on your page that has an original URL, you replace that with a page on your server and on that page you do (PHP):

```
header('Location: original.url/path/to/document');
```

Then you have the option to insert things in the database and still make it look like the user is going directly to the PayPal page.

---

**Example** If you have a site that has one page, which has a like (you can use a button, picture, etc. but my example is with a simple link) so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="paypal.site/your&code">Donate</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

You replace the `href` with a link to a page, for example: `yourdomain.com/store-first.php` and on that page you do:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect(...);
    mysql_query(...);
    header('Location: paypal.site/your&code');

?>
```

This is a **very basic** example of how it could work, but this will allow you to store something in a database and redirect the user to PayPal (or any other site or page you want) afterwards.

Comment: hi, that method sounds easy it simply went to other php function page to do the php database update. while user sitll goes to the paypal site. Problem is i had no idea where to place the header do i place it in the form action place or on the sumbit button?

Comment: Sad, dont think i could use this since the code after paypal site is auto generated by the site itself with some hashkey like digits.Unless i can know the url before hand. Thanks nevertheless

Comment: There are paypal links that do not have this hash, but if you are forced to use such a link, then there is not a whole lot you can do. You should include such things in your question though, because I answered your question to the letter, but you forgot to mention something.

Comment: Ya sorry about that, didnt notice about the send information but nevertheless its a good knowledge gain. Now im doing onclick with ajex to go to the php page stuff.